# Communicating between login.aspx and default.aspx

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, login-control

I'm new to web development. I have a login.aspx page that has an `Asp.Net` login control on it. When the users logs in and it successfully authenticates, the page automatically redirects to default.aspx. I assume this is some kind of default behavior?

But, I actually need the login information from the login page in `default.aspx.cs`. How do I get this information from that context?

In addition, I'm not always going to count on the user successfully logging in with the login control-- If I want to redirect to `default.aspx` without a login event occurring, how can I do that while also passing the login information being used?

Comment: What sort of info, specifically, do you need?  The username?  The roles?  That sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing anywhere in your web app now that the user is authenticated and logged in.

```
        MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser();

        if (mu.PasswordQuestion == null || mu.PasswordQuestion.Length < 3)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/ChangePasswordQuestion.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call `Membership.GetUser()` to get the currently-logged-in user.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the username only, you can get it like..

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name// it will return current logined username
```

Otherwise you can put the value in a session variable and then access it in the default page.

Comment: If you want to learn check this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [`LoginView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control